# TempDB full error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a web application running across a few sites, and last week I got a call to say they keep getting an error when accessing one specific page.

The error is that tempdb is full, and i'm a bit stumped as to what to do about it. I've restarted the sql server (I'm led to believe this should re-create tempdb), but still the same problem.

All the other parts of the site work fine, its just this one page (its just lists job history). Anyone any idea how i can go about working out what's causing this, i'm assuming its some bad sql somewhere.

Its a sql 2000 server, an vb.net asp(2.0) web app.

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 1):

One more possibility: maybe some dumb DBA configured TempDB to have a maximum physical size, not realizing that a runaway job that fills tempdb is going to jam everything anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certainly some problem with the SQL code & data that you are using for that page.  Use Trace or Profiler to see what it is doing on that page.